# Complex numbers unique up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, complex-numbers

> Define $(C,i)$ to be a field with a distinctive element $i$ such that
>   $i^2+1=0$, $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow C$, and that $(\mathbb{R},i) =
>  C$, that is $C$ is generated by $\mathbb{R}$ and $i$. If $(C',i')$ is another pair which satisfies these criteria, $C'
>  \cong C$. How does one show this? I have written my attempt.

---

*My proof:* Every element in $(C,i)$ is of the form 
$$p(r_1, \ldots, r_k,i)/q(s_1, \ldots, s_l,i)$$
where $r_i, s_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p,q$ multivariable polynomials with integer coefficients. Then this can be reduced (using $i^2+1=0$ )to $\alpha+i \beta $ where $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ are *unique*: if not, let $\alpha + i \beta = \alpha' + i \beta'$ and suppose wlog $\beta \not= \beta'$ we have $-\frac{\alpha-\alpha'}{\beta-\beta'}= i \notin \mathbb{R}$ contradiction.

The same goes for elements in $(C', i')$.  The isomoprhism is given by $\alpha + i \beta \mapsto \alpha + i' \beta$. The map respects addition, multiplication, is surjective, and injective (if wlog $\beta \not= 0$ and $\alpha+i'\beta = 0 $ then $i = -\alpha/\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, contradiction.)

Comment: can someone give a more general result?

Comment: Another way you could show this is by considering the map $\mathbb{R}[X] \to C$ that sends $X$ to $i$ and $\mathbb{R}$ to itself. This map is surjective due to your second condition. Now its kernel can be shown to be $(X^2 +1)$ and so the first isomorphism theorem gives $C\simeq \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$. Now since this last term doesn't depend on $C$, you get, by symmetry of the hypotheses, $C\simeq C'$